# What is the purpose of the IsWrapped property in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, xml-serialization

What is the purpose of the "IsWrapped" property in WCF. In which situation should I use this property and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [Unwrapped Messages (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750528%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):
>
> By default, the message body is formatted such that the parameters to a service operation are wrapped.

And

> [MessageContractAttribute.IsWrapped Property (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagecontractattribute.iswrapped%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):
>
> Set the value of IsWrapped to false to suppress the wrapper element into which the message body is serialized.

So, consider this (trimmed) message:

```
<s:Envelope>
  <s:Body>
    <Add>
      <n1>100</n1>
      <n2>15.99</n2>
    </Add>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

When you set `IsWrapped` to `false`, the message body won't be wrapped in an element with the action name (`Add` in this case):

```
<s:Envelope>
  <s:Body>
    <n1>100</n1>
    <n2>15.99</n2>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Properties like these are meant for interoperability, for example when writing a client to consume a service which *doesn't* expect messages to be wrapped.