# what is IsWrapped Attribute in WCF class

Tags: wcf

```
/// <summary>
/// Service Contract Class - GetItemResponse
/// </summary>
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true)]
public partial class GeItemResponse
{
}
```

In the above IsWrapped attribute is set as true , what is the use of this attribute , could anyone explain it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the IsWrapped property in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095374/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-iswrapped-property-in-wcf)

Answer (score 0):

When you set IsWrapped to false, the message body won't be wrapped in an element with the action name.
here you can read more: [What is the purpose of the IsWrapped property in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095374/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-iswrapped-property-in-wcf)

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate questions. Instead, vote to close them as duplicates. Thanks